# When do we use "sports arena" and when "sports hall"?

Tags: vocabulary

What is the difference between "sports arena" and "sports hall"? It seems that both are sometimes used interchangeably.

Comment: Could you share the results of your research, please? Just so we don't do it all over again. Dictionary definitions are likely to help, but if you've already looked there, it would be a good starting point to know what you found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hall literally could mean to be used for sports and other activities (such as 'Examination Hall, Prayer Hall etc). But Arena is usually (but not always) used as a sporting word (as in basket ball arena)

To answer your question yes both "sports arena" and "sports hall" are often used interchangeably.